# How do I specify what kinds of bounces PowerMTA delivers via local DSN?

Tags: email-server, email-bounces

I've recently been charged with overseeing the PMTA server for a small marketing company. One of the issues they have is an abundance of 'soft bounce' emails through local DSN transactions.

Is there a way for PowerMTA to only deliver hard bounces via DSN? I can get the soft bounces from the local accounting files for statistics, but they have a script that goes through the DSN emails and collects them and it is getting bogged down in softbounces - All we want delivered to the bounce account is hard bounces.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to modify the conf file to make it happen? I've read through the PMTA users guide but have not had any luck finding anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any extension of the `deliver-local-dsn` directive which would allow you to specify what kind of bounces are delivered locally. Perhaps the best solution would be to make the script more specific and only fully parse/process emails with bounces where they include "bad-mailbox", "bad-domain" and "no-answer-from-host"? [This post](http://forum.port25.com/general-discussion/best-one-line-of-code-comments/msg8671/#msg8671) on the Port25 forum may be useful.

You're probably best off browsing through the previous threads on the [Port25 forum](http://forum.port25.com/index.php) or emailing support@port25.com.

Comment: I was just really hoping I didn't have to rewrite their parsing program my first week in, haha.  But it looks like that's where this is headed.  Thanks for the backup on what I was figuring Blates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really work with hard and soft bounces in PowerMTA.  Its more of local bounces and remote bounces.  Both can contain hard and soft bounces.

You can configure what types of bounces PowerMTA captures by altering the acct-file directive.    For example...

records b,rb
        record-fields b *

b = local bounces
rb = remote bounces

Im my opinion you should always capture both, and then just control your logging application to only take from the CSV the ones you want.  In the CSV is the full breakdown of the bounce categories like bad-domain, bad-mailbox etc.

Hope this helps.
D.